# How to calculate a probability for a normal distribution in Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, probability

I am new to Python.

I have imported Scipy to calculate the probability for a set of features in a classification problem.

Let's say I have a single feature n for a certain image, and I know that the feature belongs to a normal distribution of similar features with a certain mean and SD.

At this point, how do I use the stats.norm function in Scipy? I want to calculate the probability that n belong to a normal distribution with the mean and SD that I have previously calculated. How to calculate this probability using Scipy stats.norm function? 
Is:

```
norm.pdf(feature, loc=mean, scale=SD)
```

going to give me the probability I want?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  What property of this `feature` are you looking at?  What is `norm.pdf`?  What is `feature`?

Comment: I have edited the question. The type of feature is not really important, I just ned to calculate the probability that a number n belongs to a certain distribution.

Comment: There is no `scipy.norm` function.  Do you mean `scipy.stats.norm`?  Your question is the same as, 'what is the probability of drawing the number `n` from a given distribution.'

Comment: Yes, thank you! But how to do that in SciPy? I was wondering if that was the right way to include the mean and SD.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I double-checked in R,  norm.pdf works exactly that way to give the correct probability.